Wp-contents in htdocs folder not found
0
I have started learning WordPress plugin development. In this regard, I had to get to the plugins folder which normally remains in the wp-content folder of the htdocs. But I am not finding my wp-content folder. What's the solution?
I was looking for the specific folder, but it's not there.
